# design pattern to avoid multiple-inheritance

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

Imagine there's a team for game programming, one designer focuses on data, so he creates two classes:

```
class EnemyProperties {
 public:
  int health;
};

class OrcProperties : public EnemyProperties {
 public:
  int strength;
};
```

and another programmer focuses on behaviors, as class `Enemy`, he creates an implementation:

```
class EnemyImpl : public EnemyProperties {
 public:
  void run() {}
};
```

but when it comes to implement the `Orc`, he writes this:

```
class OrcImpl : public OrcProperties, public EnemyImpl {
 public:
  void attack() {}
};
```

and he got a feeling that if there are more prototypes like this, a diamond inheritance **might** happen , so he has to make all the inheritance `virtual`.

Though virtual inheritance solved this problem, I got a feeling this a design pattern problem other than a diamond inheritance problem, simply speaking: **The `OrcImpl` should inherits from an implementation of `EnemyProperties`, and defines the behaviors which belongs to `Orc`**.

Any other design patterns or techniques to do this other than using multiple inheritance?

Or any other languages or terminologies to deal with this data-prototype inheritance problem?

P.S. I think this problem it a bit more than simple type composition, it involves a prototype inherits from another prototype, and an implementation inherits from another implementation.

Comment: [Composition vs inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), btw there is no diamond issue in your example

Comment: @Xatyrian, you are right, I read the question again and found out I'm really cares design patterns to replace multiple-inheritance, not diamond issue.

Comment: It is possible to go overboard on inheriting everything. These days I generally avoid inheritance as much as possible. Sometimes it makes perfect sense but sometimes it just ties itself up on knots.

Comment: @Xatyrian If you use composition a lot, you might end up with duplication of sub-members, and then there is no "virtual membership" to help you!

Comment: @curiousguy look for balance, one must

Comment: Take a look at Entity-Component systems. [This talk (transcript and video available)](https://kyren.github.io/2018/09/14/rustconf-talk.html) is a good introduction

Comment: Interesting thing is that all the clues you guys provided are about game designs, is that because I use a game development example or is that this problem just hurts game developers so much?

Comment: Probably because you asked from perspective of game development. Weak design of data hurts industry at wide.

Comment: It is possible to replace ALL inheritance relationships with a composition relationship. Including multiple inheritance relationships. There are trade-offs, naturally, such as the need for a class composed of (instances of) other classes to coordinate behaviour of all the objects it contains. Sometimes inheritance, even multiple inheritance, is the more practical solution, sometimes composition is.  Religiously avoiding one or the other - as distinct from making engineering trade-offs and picking a solution suitable for the job at hand - tends to be more trouble than it is worth.